# React: For a web application how to add different functionally on Buttons for different views(Mobile and Desktop View)

Tags: reactjs

While working on a demo project in React, at a certain point i want the functionality of a button to work differently in mobile view and desktop view.So i just want to know what is the best way to do so..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try react-responsive package .
Show the difference button based on Different view port

[React-responsive library reference](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive)

```
import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Device Test!</div>
      <div>You are a desktop or laptop</div>
      <MediaQuery query="(min-device-width: 1824px)">
        <div>You also have a huge screen</div>
        <Button onClick={handleMethod()} />
      </MediaQuery>
      <MediaQuery query="(max-width: 1224px)">
        <Button onClick={handleAnotherMethod()} />
      </MediaQuery>
  </div>
);
```